# NodeJS - Best way to handle private messaging?

Tags: node.js, chat, private

I want to create a private message system using NodeJS and websockets.
I was wondering what the best way is to create such system.

Is it better to create 1 nodeJS server and bind listen-event for each user, or should I create a unique port/server for each conversation between 2 users.
i.e.

> conversation 1 (user1 & user2): port 8080
>
> conversation 2 (user2 & user3): port 8081
>
> conversation 3 (user1 & user3): port 8082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it better to create 1 nodeJS server and bind listen-event for each
>   user, or should I create a unique port/server for each conversation
>   between 2 users. i.e.

Neither.

---

You can easily create a private conversation between two users with one server listening on one port and allowing users to connect to the server and then identify which other user they want to have a private conversation with.

1. A user identifies themselves to the server with some sort of credential when they login and connect to the server.  Your server then knows which user belongs to which connection.
2. The server can then facilitate a private conversation between any two users by simply allowing userA to pass messages to userB and vice/versa, but not allowing anyone else access to those messages.  No private server per user is needed.  No custom port is needed.  You do need some sort of user authentication service so you can know which user is which with some appropriate level of credibility.

You can see some pieces of what you're asking about in this [socket.io demo chat server](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

Here's a more detailed description for how this works:

1. UserA connects to the server and identifies themselves.
2. UserB connects to the server and identifies themselves.
3. UserC connects to the server and identifies themselves.
4. UserA sends a message to the server instructing the server to send a private message to userC.
5. The server receives that message from UserA and forwards it on to UserC.
6. UserC receives the private message from userA.
7. The server does not store the message from UserA or ever send it to any other users (thus making it a private message).
8. UserC can then respond to UserA using the same mechanism.

Note: It is a requirement of pretty much any scheme that you have both user authentication and you have a user identifier.  You will then also have to surface that in a user interface so that a given user can identify which currently connected user they wish to communicate with.

Comment: I'm using a login system with a unique e-mailaddress for each user. When the user succesfully logged in, two PHP sessions are created: One with the unique user id and one with the unique e-mailaddress.

When the user is logged, and clicks the right button, a popup modal is shown with a list of nodeJS server/port connected users. I am using a user interface like this awesome codepen: [link](http://codepen.io/Momciloo/pen/bEdbxY)

So since the information is stored in a PHP session, how could I identify in JavaScript (nodeJS) which user want to send a message to some one else?

Comment: @Piet - You will need access to a session in node.js.  I have no idea whether you can get access to the PHP session from node.js or not.  That depends upon a bunch of characteristics of your deployment and the cookie settings in the session.  If the node.js server was a sub-domain of the PHP server, then you could probably configure the PHP cookie to allow access from the node.js sub-domain server.  But, even then I don't know if that will help you.  You have seriously complicated things by using multiple server architectures here and needing to share login between them.

Comment: @Piet - Can you do the whole server in just one system so you don't have to share login sessions between servers?  socket.io can be used from PHP or node.js could do the rest of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So you suggest that I should code the whole message system in websockets for PHP?

Comment: @Piet - Well actually since I like node.js, I would code the whole thing in node.  But, the point is that mixing systems is making things harder rather than easier.

Comment: Yes I like node.js too, but the login and many other code is written in PHP so I will try to find some information about that in google. Thanks for pointing me out!